how to fix this Error: qrc:/main.qml: No such file or directory
I'm developing a very basic QML GUI for a C++ project, but I'm having trouble adding file URLs to the program. I've tried using absolute paths, ./path, and ../path, but none of them work. Whenever I try to add an image or code file URL, I keep getting the error 'qrc:/main.qml: No such file or directory'. I'm using Qt Creator on Ubuntu. How can I fix this problem?
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "game.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Game>("Game", 1, 0, "Game");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}



Are you actually using a resource file? Did you include it in the executable?

@musicamante how should i add it in the executable. i tired to do so but i couldn't figure out the right way. and also when i want to use an image local url should i include the image file somewhere ? it would be awesome if you could explain this in answers part.

Did you properly study the Qt resource system documentation?

please add the error output

The default prefix path has been changed from Qt 6.5 on to "/qt/qml". So this could be your problem.
Try to change your path to qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml
Have a look at this page for more details: QTP0001

qrc:/qt/qml/main.qml: No such file or directory, Qt 6.6.2
